# Custom Logging, how to bypass Limit Exceptions

Tags: rest-api, governorlimits

I'm developing a custom log system for Blackbox Testing.
The goal is to log everything until transaction ends or an exception is thrown - **even if apex throws a Limit Exception and rolls back all changes(even asynchronously methods)!**

To prevent a rollback of log entrys i tried to do REST callouts, but ran into the 10 callout Limit.

Could i use Remote Actions instead?
As they can only be called from JS I'm not sure if this would be a feasable solution.

did you do that before, any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If LimitException is thrown, AFAIK you are totally dead. You can't catch them - they are the equivalent of an OutOfMemoryError in Java where the system straight vomits and your code is no longer allowed to execute.

In Apex, this means you can't do ANYTHING in Apex after they are thrown, including the commit of the pending transaction. If they are thrown in your current execution context, your "VM" is considered persona non grata. Your code never sees the error because it is no longer allowed to execute after it is thrown.

Can you give more detail on what you are trying to do, and why? Why are Remote Actions even considered? There is no way I'm aware of, for instance, to do any sort of callout (or literally anything) after a LimitException is thrown. If you hit it, the user (or developer running a test) is going to get an on-screen error, no exceptions.

LimitException is the black death - to be avoided at all costs and if it's a possibility in theory, you have to fix its root cause.

Comment: Thanks @jkraybill! I tried doing callouts during the Blackbox Test runs, that worked for 10 callouts and then I got the Limit Exception.
So I was looking for another way to save log entrys until running into limits. Now I know, there actually is none!

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a fairly basic setup before adding log messages to a static logging class (as a single string if i recall).  The log is not persisted except in catch blocks and at the end of processing when StaticLogClass.persistLog() is called which emailed it to a dev.  Depending on the context (and likely limits that would be hit) the logging was altered to SOQL insertion / HTTP POST callout.   Have to watch for the heap limits for that logging string though... Manual and fiddly but worked. I'm not sure how you'd go about coping with every limit that might be hit.  I'm sure you can test for how much of certain governor limits you've used and depending on which have not been exhausted, determine how to persist the log?